# JS alerts not displaying until popup window is closed

Tags: javascript, popup, alert

I have a webpage that executes a JS function when a table cell is clicked.  In the function I do some data manipulation and then do a new window as a popup and some document writes that add text and images to the popup.  The script that is running has some alerts following all the document.close for the popup but these do not get displayed until the popup window is closed.  Is this because the calling function is suspended at this point and the focus is on the popup?  Can't find a way to have any code in the calling function execute until the popup is closed.  Here is a code snippet in which the argument html is a string variable with the text to be added to the document body.

```
newWindow.document.open("","PlaqueImage");
newWindow.document.write(html);
newWindow.document.close();
alert("document created");
```

Can't get the alert to display.   The .close does not seem to affect the script if it is not included but was under the impression it was required to complete the writing of the text.

What I am really trying to accomplish is to open a popup and display text on initial load.  Then I want the script to continue and allow for an image to be added with whatever code is required (.appendChild ?? perhaps).  But it seems like the script stops running while the popup is open and only resumes after it closes if the alert non-display is indicative of the calling function being suspended until the close of the popup.

Comment: You could try to wrap the window logic into an async.

Comment: Not sure I understand.